# Why this code generate a heap error after returning from main?

Tags: c++, opencv, heap-corruption

I have this code which uses opencv. I simplified it to make sure that the error is not relates to any other part of application. The code is:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv)
{
    int num_images = 2;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images(num_images);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> masks(num_images);
    vector<Point> corners(num_images);
    vector<Size> sizes(num_images);

    sizes[0] = Size(100, 100);
    sizes[1] = Size(100, 100);

    corners[0] = Point(0, 0);
    corners[1] = Point(0, 0);

    images[0].create(sizes[0], CV_8SC3);
    images[0] = cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0);

    images[1].create(sizes[1], CV_8SC3);
    images[1] = cv::Scalar(0,255, 0);

    masks[0].create(sizes[0], CV_8SC1);
    masks[1].create(sizes[1], CV_8SC1);

    masks[0] = 255;
    masks[0](Rect(0, 0, 50, 100)) = 0;

    masks[1] = 0;
    masks[1](Rect(0, 0, 50, 100)) = 255;

    Ptr<SeamFinder> seam_finder = new detail::VoronoiSeamFinder();

    seam_finder->find(images, corners, masks);

}
```

If I comment out seam_finder->find line, it is working properly, but when it is added to code, I am getting error when application exit.

The error generated at line 1424 on VCTools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c and the expression is: _pFirstBlock ==pHead.

Why this line corrupt heap and how I can fix it.

Comment: "I simplified it to make sure that the error is not relates to any other part of application" - apart from the `find` function, which you say is the cause of the problem, but don't show us. There's no way to guess what that might be doing to the heap. Can you reduce this to a [self-contained test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MikeSeymour It is a self contain code. Find is part of OpenCV. I included all part of my code (other than includes which include opencv headers)

Comment: @mans - `The error generated at line 1424 on VCTools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c and the expression is: _pFirstBlock ==pHead.`  That code is part of the runtime so is not that helpful.  What function in `find` causes the issue?  Look at your call stack.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie As I mentioned, find is part of opencv and when I run the code, it is not generating any error, in fact it comes out of the function without any run time error, but when application finishes, (main returns) I am getting the error. At that time, I don't have any stack information as there is no call stack.

Comment: @mans Even outside of `main`, there is a call stack, as that message came from somewhere -- it didn't just appear out of thin air.  When that dialog box (which I suspect it is) pops up, go to the debug option and hit "Break All".  Then you will see the call stack in the debugger "call stack" window.

Comment: Probably in the destructor of one of the classes.

Comment: I have no problem running your code on my machine after modifying the part where you assign masks values. Can you change it to something like this:     masks[1] = cv::Scalar(0);    Mat roi(50, 50, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255));    roi.copyTo(masks[1](Rect(0, 0, 50, 50))); and re-run your program?